# Do you need to clearly distinguish dream scenes from reality in comics books?

Tags: comics

Do you need to clearly distinguish dream scenes from reality in comics books? Sometimes dream scenes are grayed a little bit to distinguish them, but do you have to do it? When should you distinguish them graphically and when should you not? I am thinking of not greying them, but without making the character dreaming suddenly wake up, I am not sure how I can tell readers it likely was a dream.

Comment: There are different ways of graphically distinguishing a dream sequence in comic from the regular scenes. So if it's just that particular "greying" style that makes you want to avoid it, you could consider alternatives. (If you have a strip format with panels, changign the panel borders is effective.) In any cases, confusing your readers is only a good idea if that is actually your intention.

Comment: Do you want to give the reader an immediate clue that this is a dream scene, or you want to reveal it only later?